# determine point in triangle

Tags: geometry

How can I determine the point of X on the map, or the distance between X and either end point.

The dashed line from X to point is perpendicular. The distance between each point is on the map, and the points would be approx:

```
var a = {latitude:48, longitude:-90};
var b = {latitude:49, longitude:-92}
var c = {latitude:48.25, longitude:-91.8};
```

Map image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMcxP.png]

Comment: I guess, we also have the exact coordinates of the vertices of the triangle, don't we?

Comment: In this example yes (var a,b,c), although I want to know how to figure it out myself not just the answer. The distances were rounded on the map. The points are: 48,-90;  49,-92;  48.25,-91.8

Comment: Let's call $h$ the length of the dotted line. Use law of cosines to find angle between the side with $84$ and the side with $114$, call that $A$. By basic trig $h/84=sinA$. Thus $h=84sinA. You could've also use Heron's formula to calculate the area and then find out h. Anyways, Say $X$ can be represented by $(x,y)$ than $(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2=h^2$. We're $(x_1,y_1)$ is the point you have that is an end of the dotted line. Then use the other two points to come up with a linear relationship. Solve the system of equations.

Comment: Also, this is only good if in this area the earth is not significantly round. So if it's kind of flat, this is a good approximation.